# Python digit formatting

Tags: python-3.x, formatting

I was taking some PCAP certification practice tests when I stumbled upon some sort of digit formatting, I don't really understand what it is and how it works.

**Choose the correct statements from the following.**

```
The output of print("-%07d"%555.55) is same as the output of print("%7d"%555.55)

The output of print("-%07d"%555.55) is same as the output of print("-07d"%555)
(Correct)

The output of print("-%02d"%555.55) is same as the output of print("-%2d"%555.55)
(Correct)

The output of print("-%02d"%555.55) is same as the output of print("-%02d"%555)
(Correct)
```

Comment: All of the print statements where there is no % in between the string and the float are going to raise a Syntax Error.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to add the modulo when making the question, I updated it now.

Comment: I think @alexpdev was referring to the `"-07d"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified understanding of it.

- The modulo or `%` character is the formatting character.
- The `d` means integer only, so no floating point values will be used.
- The `-` just makes it negative.
- The integer before the `d` indicates the minimum number of characters desired in output.
- If there is a `0` in front of the integer it means that it should be padded with leading zeros in order to reach the desired number of characters.

if the `d` was an `f` then it would allow floating point values and any zero padding would be done at the end